# Docker start a fresh instance(without the user data) of a stopped/running docker container.

Tags: docker

Is there a way to start a fresh instance(i.e. without having any user related data from the previous run) of a container without actually removing it and then reissuing the same command.

For example:

```
$ docker run --name some-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis
$ docker stop some-redis && docker start some-redis
or $ docker restart some-redis
```

will restart the container, but the user data from the previous run will persist. Whereas I am looking for an equivalent of the following:

```
$ docker run --name some-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis
$ docker stop some-redis && docker rm some-redis
$ docker run --name some-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis
```

Comment: If you don't want that data then why don't you delete that container and then recreate?

Comment: Because during development it's very annoying to find the correct command with envs, port, volumes etc and then start it again. Whereas docker already knows these options.